# Session after login unsuccess and in login.php check for it, not redirect it to homepage (index.php)

Tags: php

Session after login unsuccess and in `login.php` not redirect it to homepage (`index.php`).
example link ([pos.beckie168.com](http://pos.beckie168.com)).

please help me

```
username : tepbopea
password : 8886188
```

Code Login.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require 'dbconfig/db.php';
    $a='Username';
    $b='password';
    if(isset($_POST['btnsend'])){
        $name=$_POST['txtusername'];
        $pwd= $_POST['txtpwd'];
        if(trim($name)==''){
            $a="Name required";
            }elseif(trim($pwd)==''){
                $b="Password required";
                }else{
                    $sql="select * from tbluser where username='$name' and password='$pwd'";
                    $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                    $num= mysqli_num_rows($query);
                    if($num>0){
                        $_SESSION['userlogin']=$name;
                        header('location:index.php');
                        }else{

                            echo"<span style='color:red;margin-left:40%;margin-top:20px;font-family:Segoe,sans-serif;'>
                            Wrong Username or  Password</span>";
                            }
                    }
        }
```

Comment: please share your code...what you've tried so far

Comment: we will not know how and why its not working if you dont show us your code. We're not all hackers who can hack your server and get the code.

Comment: Your login script is completely useless because it doesnt server this purpose, its **vulnerable to sql injection**, just enter `' OR '1'='1` in username and password http://www.veracode.co.uk/security/sql-injection

Comment: remove # from action attribute of your form..

Comment: Hopefully this is just a simple example because I have to hope you are not storing plaintext passwords...?

Comment: i remove # from action unsuccess

Comment: use `exit();` after `header`

Comment: no. not redirect to homepage

Answer (score 0):

To Try-

```
"<script>
        window.location = "index.php";
 </script>"
```

Just replace

```
 header('location:index.php');
```